# Gradle suddenly doesn't build Arm8Release any more

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

When I say

```
./gradlew installArm8Release
```

I get this error:

```
:app:generateJsonModelArm8Release UP-TO-DATE
:app:externalNativeBuildArm8Release FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildArm8Release'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\TestApp\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\arm8Release\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I believe my Gradle configuration has somehow been corrupted because as you can see it says on `:app:generateJsonModelArm8Release` that it is up to date but as you can see from the error below `android_gradle_build.json` isn't there at all.

The following line works fine, though:

```
./gradlew installArm7Release
```

It's only `Arm8Release` that fails although it used to work before. This makes me think that somehow something got corrupted. I have already tried the following:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

All to no avail. It refuses to build the `Arm8Release` target. I have also tried deleting the `.externalNativeBuild` directory and running

```
./gradlew wrapper
```

again. But it didn't solve the issue either.

I have also rebooted the system to make sure any gradle daemon is gone but the error is still there.

I'm pretty much out of ideas now. All targets are working fine except `Arm8Release`. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record: Deleting really everything from my build directory except the source and resource files solved this issue. So it seems like

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

doesn't really clean *everything*...

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio 3.5 (and probably above), that missing file is under a .cxx folder, so deleting the build folder has no effect. Cleaning build doesn't help either. Instead an invalidate cache and restart did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add  `--rerun-tasks` to your gradlew command, e.g.

```
./gradlew installArm8Release --rerun-tasks
```

Answer (score -1):

just restart Android Studio, it worked for me.